# Is it possible to have two keyPressed events at one jTextArea?

Tags: java, swing

I've been working on a project, a basic kinetic novel, no frills, just basic `JTextArea`s with `keyPressed` events. I've been wondering, is it possible to handle more than one function in one `keyPressed` event?

I have tried making two `.setText` functions but still it doesn't work.

```
private void jTextArea1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    // first sentence
    jTextArea1.append("It was the midst of the war.");
    // second sentence
    jTextArea1.setText("second sentence");
}
```

Comment: Yes , but `setText` will obviously replace the whole text.

Comment: Also, is it possible to have two KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)?

Comment: Why would you have two? Everything you can do in these two is possible to do in one. In standard use i don't think you need two `Listener`s

Comment: As Berger said, `setText()` will replace the whole text, you wouldn't see the effects of that `append()`. Yes, you can apply as many `KeyListener` as you want (but you probably need just one)

Comment: You can do a counter to know how often the user has pressed a key so you can append the sentence you want. Otherwise all Actions in your KeyPressed Event will be called for every key that is pressed

Comment: maybe he wants something like shift+f as example

Comment: The Key Bindings API might be a better choice